# jQuery URL bit.ly shortener

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp, bit.ly, url-shortener

Will someone please help me with this jQuery bit.ly URL shortener?

The code is as follows:

```
function shortenUrl(urlMatch)
{
    var urlMatch = urlMatch
    var username="myusername";
    var key = 'R_897b82b73568ea74fffbafa5a7b846d';
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://api.bit.ly/v3/shorten",
        data:{longUrl:urlMatch,apiKey:key,login:username},
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success:function(v)
        {
            var shortUrl=v.data.url;
            return shortUrl;
        }
    });
}

$('button').click(function(){
    var urlMatch = $(this).val();
    var newUrl = shortenUrl(urlMatch);
    $('#menu').html(newUrl);
});
```

And whenever I run the script it returns this code in the console:

```
jsonp1304728172115({ data : [ ] , "status_code" : 500, "status_txt": "missing_arg_uri"})
```

Comment: Missing parameter "format": "json" ? Here is my version of code: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771397/jquery-on-the-fly-url-shortener/7005673#7005673

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

`data:{longUrl:urlMatch,apiKey:key,login:username},`

If jsonp is anything like json, then you're data argument is not formed correctly:

`data:"{'longUrl':" + urlMatch + ",'apiKey':" + key + ",'login':" + username + "}",`

The above code is not tested, but it should be similar.

Comment: Nick, jquery takes care of this translation

Comment: ah yes, i think you are correct, because a jsonp call is GET. The code you posted does not work, but i got it working by just including all of the variables in the actual url.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it was a GET. Good to know.

Answer (score 1):

This: `urlMatch = $(this).val();` will get the button text into urlMatch, is this what you want?

Also, the `return` on the callback will not reach the function, because `ajax()` is an asynchronous function. To make it synchronous, add `async:false` to `ajax()` parameters.

And `return` will not work as well, so you have to assign the result to a global var.

But the best would be replacing `return shortUrl;` with `$('#menu').html(shortUrl);`, since that's the outcome that you are looking for. And you don't need `async:false` for that, which will block your code and temporarily lock the browser.

If all fails, try passing the parameters on the query string itself. You may want to [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601315/jquery-ajax-call-to-bit-ly-returns-results-in-ie-but-not-ff-or-chrome).

Comment: well the actual problem i am having is there is an error message returned, and i cannot figure out as to why.

Comment: please check the content of urlMatch being passed as parameter

Comment: @mcbeav > i just checked the documentation and `async:false` can't be used with jsonp, so you'll have to go with the second option.

Comment: i finally got it working, every code snippit i found on the web did not work correctly, and i guess i just don't understand API's, because googles URL shortener API documentation is not very informative or helpful at all.

Comment: "If all fails, try passing the parameters on the query string itself." it's there on the original answer

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a semicolon after "var urlMatch = urlMatch"